# Помогите стереть надпись в консоли

Tags: c

После каждого нажатия "enter" выводить следующие n-значений таблицы после них надпись "нажмите "enter"", нажимаешь "enter" надпись пропадает таблица выводится дальше на n значений, при чем если пролистать ее до предыдущих n-значений то надписи "нажмите "enter"" нету  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int N;
    int variant,i,n;
    double x1,x2,delta,y,x;
    do
    {
        printf("Vyberit' variant obchyslennja funktsii f(x)\n");
        printf("1 - za tochkamy; 2 - za krokom zminy\n");
        scanf("%d",&variant);
        if(variant==1)
        {
            printf("Vy vybraly variant: %d\n", variant);
            printf("Vvedit' N, x1, x2\n");
            scanf("%d%lf%lf",&N,&x1,&x2);
            printf("x1=%.2f  x2=%.2f  N=%d\n",x1,x2,N);
            getch();
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("|  N  |\t\t\t  X  \t\t\t|\t\t\tF(X) \t\t\t|\n");
            delta=(x2-x1)/N;
            for(x=x1,n=1,i=0;x<x2,n<N,i<N;x=x+delta,n++,i++)
            {
                y=(x*x*x)-3*(x*x)+4;
                printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("| %2d  |\t\t\t%5.2f   \t\t|\t\t      %6.2f\t\t\t|\n",n,x,y);
                if((i+1)% 10 == 0)
                {
                    printf("Press any key...\n");
                    getch();
                }
            }
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
        else if(variant==2) \\ не доделано
        {
            printf("Vy vybraly variant: %d", variant);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Vash vybir ne vidpovidae vymogam!\n");
        }
    }
    while ((variant!=1)&&(variant!=2));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: покажи код ....

Comment: В зависимости от свойств вашего терминала, вам может помочь, например, `printf("\b\b\b\b")` (столько символов `\b`, сколько в тексте `Press any key...`. Только уберите `\n` из `printf("Press any key...\n");`.

Comment: уже поправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень хорошо помню `C`, но может быть так?

```
 if((i+1)% 10 == 0)
 {
     printf("Press any key...");
     getch();
     printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
 }
```

Comment: уже пробовал такой вариант, не работает(

Comment: @RuslanSuprun: А вы не забыли убрать `\n` из первого `printf`?